# Run Node.js command from package.json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, browserify

Can i run  this command node.js from package.json ?

```
"browserify file.js -o bundle.js"
```

if i can how i can do this and how to execute it without using command prompt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

npm gives you the ability to run aliased commands that you can store in your package.json file. Two basics are `npm test` and `npm start`, which respectively test and start your application (if you provide the commands that would do those things).

You can put your aliased commands in a nested object w/in the **scripts** property. To run commands that aren't either start or test, you have to use `npm run <command alias>`. So, you could do `npm run bundle`.

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "some test command",
   "start": "some start command",
   "bundle": "browserify file.js -o bundle.js"
}
```

Also, to clarify, you can't execute code **from/in** a JSON file, JSON is just a data interchange format.

Hope that helps!